# How to find X number of points in between two lat long pairs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, latitude-longitude

I have two points in latitude longitude web mercator:

```
var point1 = [32.043732,-99.563599]

var point2 = [32.591515,-97.630005]
```

How would I obtain 3 points in between those two latitude longitude pairs in javascript function that takes X points?

Comment: two points define a line. so use standard line equations... Or do you need to produce grand-circle curved line points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation):

```js
function getPoints(point1, point2, num) {
    var d0 = (point2[0] - point1[0]) / (num + 1);
    var d1 = (point2[1] - point1[1]) / (num + 1);
    var points = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        points.push({
            x: point1[0] + d0 * i,
            y: point1[1] + d1 * i
        });
    }
    return points;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJnbV/)